# Creating a co-occurrence matrix with years and words

Tags: python, matrix, network-analysis

I have a dataset of abstracts from conferences and have a dictionary with dictionaries of each year's word frequencies. I want to turn this dictionary of dictionaries into a matrix that compares the frequencies from each year against the other years to see which years are most similar to one another.

I made the dictionary into a pandas dataframe. Remember: it's words and years.

```
wordsdf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(word_dfs, orient='index')
```

I'm trying to get the years as columns and rows to compare in the coocc matrix. But so far because they aren't all ints I can't just use the dot product. Any suggestions?

I've tried this to no avail:

```
# #to create a co-occurrence matrix
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from itertools import combinations
from collections import Counter

sentences = wordsdf
vocab = set(word_tokenize(' '.join(str(sentences)))
token_sent_list = [word_tokenize(sen) for sen in sentences]

co_occ = {ii:Counter({jj:0 for jj in vocab if jj!=ii}) for ii in vocab}
k=2

for sen in token_sent_list:
    for ii in range(len(sen)):
        if ii < k:
            c = Counter(sen[0:ii+k+1])
            del c[sen[ii]]
            co_occ[sen[ii]] = co_occ[sen[ii]] + c
        elif ii > len(sen)-(k+1):
            c = Counter(sen[ii-k::])
            del c[sen[ii]]
            co_occ[sen[ii]] = co_occ[sen[ii]] + c
        else:
            c = Counter(sen[ii-k:ii+k+1])
            del c[sen[ii]]
            co_occ[sen[ii]] = co_occ[sen[ii]] + c

# # Having final matrix in dict form lets you convert it to different python data structures
co_occ = {ii:dict(co_occ[ii]) for ii in vocab}
co_occ
```

Comment: Hi Sophie, welcome to Stack Overflow. Kindly, add your relevant code to your question so other members could be able to help you.

Comment: Sorry about that, Khalid. I attached the code that's currently not working. Thanks!